# Send email if there is an attachment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The macro will send if there is an email address.

I don't want it sending if there is no attachment.

I want it to still skip if it cannot find an email address.

```vb
Sub CreateStatement()
    Dim EApp As Object
     Set EApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

     Dim EItem As Object

    'Dim EApp As Outlook.Application
    'Set EApp = New Outlook.Application

    'Dim EItem As Outlook.MailItem
    'Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Dim path As String
    path = "K:\"

    Dim RList As Range
    Set RList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))

    Dim R As Range

    For Each R In RList
        Set EItem = EApp.CreateItem(0)
    
        With EItem
            On Error Resume Next
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
            .To = R.Offset(0, 2)
            .Subject = "December Statement: "
            .Attachments.Add (path & R.Offset(0, 3))
            .Body = "Dear " & R & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
              & "Please find your " & R.Offset(0, 4) & " attached."
            .Display
        End With

    Next R

    Set EApp = Nothing
    Set EItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Dir()` to check if a file exists.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the line preventing it from throwing an exception. You really should only use exception handling when you can't realistically plan to test for it. As Tim stated, you can test if a file exists with `Dir()`.

To prevent it sending on no attachments is easy - but your code doesn't send. It displays. I'm going to assume you want to display if there's no attachments.

```vb
With EApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .To = R.Offset(0, 2)
    .Subject = "December Statement: "
    .Attachments.Add (Path & R.Offset(0, 3))
    .Body = "Dear " & R & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
        & "Please find your " & R.Offset(0, 4) & " attached."
    On Error GoTo 0

    If .Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        .Send
    Else
        .Display
    End If
End With
```